# How can I have unmodified case buttons using Semantic-UI?

Tags: css, uppercase, semantic-ui

[Semantic-Ui](http://semantic-ui.com/) seems to provide only `uppercase` buttons (via `text-transform`). What's the best way to use this UI framework without `CSS` *modifying* my button's case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your own CSS, simply set `text-transform` to initial:

```css
.ui.button {
    text-transform: initial;
}
```

The `initial` property will make your button's text adhere to the text placed within the HTML.

```
HTML    Uppercase    Initial
Foo     FOO          Foo
fOO     FOO          fOO
FOO     FOO          FOO
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `text-transform:none !important;` to your buttons.

Comment: `!important` is bad practice and can almost always be avoided.

Comment: I don't hate anyone. `!important` is just bad practice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css. If the property doesn't override existing properties without `!important` specified, you can almost always solve the problem by increasing your selector's specificity.